# How use conditional relationship in eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a 'conversation_message' table and separate sender role by column 'sender_type' (admin/user). Both of admin & user in a different table. But when I call the model, that showed error *Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null*

Table column and data

```
| id | id_group | id_reply | id_sender | sender_type | message 
| 1  | 1 | null | 3 | admin | Hi, I'm admin
| 2  | 1 | 1 | 3 | admin | I wanna give u promo
| 3  | 1 | 2 | 18 | user | What's promo ?
```

I've tried if conditional with column value, but it doesn't work.

**Conversation_message.php**

```php
public function sender(){
        switch($this->sender_type){
            case "user":
                return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_sender', 'id');
            case "admin":
                return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class, 'id_sender', 'id');
            default:
                return;           
        }
    }
```

**InboxController.php**

```php
public function message_detail_chat($groupId){
        $data = [];
        $data['messages'] = Conversation_message::with('replies')
                        ->with('sender')
                        ->with('recipients')
                        ->where(['id_group' => $groupId])->get();
}
```

I expect to use conditional model by column value 'sender_type' but the actual output is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

laravel provide query scope your can read it from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes

```
   function userSender(){
      $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_sender', 'id');
      }

     function adminSender(){

       return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class, 'id_sender', 'id');

     }

public function scopeSender($query)
{
    return $query
          ->when($this->sender_type === 'user',function($q){
              return $q->with('userSender');
         })
         ->when($this->sender_type === 'admin',function($q){
              return $q->with('adminSender');
         }); 

}
```

Now you can access your Sender like this

```
     Conversation_message::Sender()->first();
```

This should give you the right Sender. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry to late to reply, that code still error, `sender` field not appear in response.

`{
 id: 3,
 id_group: 3,
 id_reply: null,
 sender_id: 1,
 sender_type: "admin", 
 message: "<p>Min</p>",
 created_at: "2019-05-10 08:31:22",
 updated_at: "2019-05-10 08:31:22",
 is_deleted: "0",
 date_readable: "5 days ago"
}`

Comment: when you get the error and what exactly error you get?

Comment: Actually I got no error message, but I want show `sender` field at response below. I access Sender with this code

`Conversation_message::Sender()
                                                    ->where('id_group', $user_group[$i]['id'])
                                                    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
                                                    ->get();`

Comment: simply echo `sender_type` if you know how to print the data